# Strategy for maintaining offline repository safely using git

Tags: version-control, git, source-code, backups

I use git for versioning. Just yesterday I was working on refactoring my Python code base. After adding a test I found that I had [introduced a bug](https://github.com/anshbansal/general/commit/a862539ad3533329b9484c701dffadfbc6feca61) in one of project euler solutions. So I checked out a previous version offline, found the diff and went back to latest version and fixed the problem.

It was a bit after that I found a mess up had been done due to this. I use .gitignore to leave many of the unneeded files or WIP things out of git. I found that using checkout and going back to the latest version deleted some files which were not checked in. Now I am finding that a new repo that I keep in an ignored Folder is completed cleaned. It did not have much so far but still all is gone.

So I am confused about what is a good way to keep offline codebase intact in case there are many such folders/files that I do not want to check in? Also how to organize codebase on local for new projects? Just take backups on a drive?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow, but is frequently duplicated there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git` does warn you if it is going to modify or delete untracked or uncommitted files. Don't take this lightly.

Do check in *everything* you work on, all WIP stuff, all temporary stuff. If you can't carelessly delete a file outright, track it. Make a lot of small commits. Once something started to work, commit it; don't mind that it's yet imperfect.

If you care about cleanliness, use separate branches: keep 'master' clean and wildly experiment on feature branches. Branching is *incredibly* cheap in `git`. When you want to pull a feature in, use `merge` or `cherry-pick`.

If amidst a change you need to check out another commit, `git stash` is your friend. You can `git stash pop` on the same or on a *different* branch; great when you just realized that you had started working on a wrong branch.

And again, look at all your untracked files as useless trash that a janitor may choose to take out at any moment. If something is not trash, `git add` it.